# Remove Meta-boxes (Yoast SEO plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, post-meta, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WordPress SEO by Yoast: Hide Meta boxes in posts for non-admins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/wordpress-seo-by-yoast-hide-meta-boxes-in-posts-for-non-admins)

I was wondering how to remove Meta-boxes from the post page. I would like that only administrators or editors could see these. I saw similar topics on the forum, but none of them appears to be working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See [WordPress SEO by Yoast: Hide Meta boxes in posts for non-admins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/wordpress-seo-by-yoast-hide-meta-boxes-in-posts-for-non-admins)

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'yoast_is_toast', 99);
function yoast_is_toast(){
    //capability of 'manage_plugins' equals admin, therefore if NOT administrator
    //hide the meta box from all other roles on the following 'post_type' 
    //such as post, page, custom_post_type, etc
    if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'post_type', 'normal');
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I replace code in Line 32:  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) ); with this?

Comment: No... you need to only add the function snippet above to your functions.php file, nothing else, except change post_type to your required type i.e. post.  The references to line numbers in the other answer only explain whats in the plugin file itself for reference on where I sourced further information. Normally you would just get the name of the metabox from the ID parameter on the edit screen. I didnt have yoast installed at time, so I just dug into plugin files