# Hide Meta Boxes for Non-Admins

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, themes, metabox, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a review based wordpress site where I have a page for each different company where there users can review them. The theme I use adds a custom post type called "review" and I have used Press Permit to create limited user accounts that can modifying some parts of these review pages.

I wanted to hide some of the Meta Boxes that they should not have access to such as Yoast SEO, GD Star Ratings, etc. I followed the instructions from some other posts on this website, however it does not hide the meta boxes as it should.

I have added the following code at the end of the "functions.php" in my Theme directory as per the instructions at [WordPress SEO by Yoast: Hide Meta boxes in posts for non-admins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/wordpress-seo-by-yoast-hide-meta-boxes-in-posts-for-non-admins)

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'hide_yoastseo_metabox', 99);

function hide_yoastseo_metabox()
{
    if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins'))
    {
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'review', 'normal');
    }
}
```

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Does lowering the priority of your `add_action()` call here help? This was mentioned by [Kid Slimmer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/29054/kid-slimmer) and [Piet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2015/piet) in the very post you linked to you, in this comment → https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91184/33604

Their code example uses a priority of `10000` instead of `99`, like you're using – try updating your priority to `500` or `1000` or something to begin with, and see if anything changes.

You also may find better luck by checking user capabilities *before* adding the action itself, which was also demonstrated in the comment I linked to above.

So, for example, something like this *might* work a little better:

```
if( ! current_user_can('activate_plugins') ) {
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'hide_yoastseo_metabox', 1000);
}

function hide_yoastseo_metabox() {
    remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'review', 'normal');
}
```

Other than these recommendations, the only other thing I could think of would be to double-check all your values for `remove_meta_box()` – make sure `'wpseo_meta'` is the proper metabox id for the Yoast metabox you're trying to remove, `'review'` is the proper post type that you want to hide the metabox on, and `'normal'` is the proper priority for the metabox you're targeting. You can read more about `remove_meta_box()` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box).

**Also**, not to insult your intelligence here, but I'm curious: are you accessing your "review" post type edit screens in different capability levels? If you're only viewing things in your admin from your full-capability superadmin account, then code that only applies to limited-capability accounts won't run for you. Make sure you've got a test account with the limited capabilities you're testing, and try viewing things from within that account.

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_function() {
    global $current_user;
    if($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator') {
        add_meta_box(your parameters);
        // fill in your parameters
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','your_function');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?